Relation between the number of curvature functions and dimensions in GR
I am reading Weinberg's Gravitation and Cosmology. On page 10, it reads

In $D$ dimensions there will be $D(D+1)/2$ independent metric functions $g_{ij}$, and our freedom to choose the $D$ coordinates at will allows us to impose $D$ arbitrary functional relations on the $g_{ij}$, leaving $C$ functions that truly express the inner properties of the space, where $C=\frac{D(D+1)}{2}-D=\frac{D(D-1)}{2}$.

I don't understand the "$D$ arbitrary functional relations on the $g_{ij}$". Can someone write one such functional relation on the $g_{ij}$?

In general relativity, we usually exploit this freedom when choosing a gauge. This is very common when dealing with gravitational waves. My example will be focused on gravitational waves. I'll take the equations in here from Chap 18 of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's Gravitation. The equation numbers correspond to the numbers in MTW.
When doing gravitational waves, it is common to consider a metric given by
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu},$$
where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric and $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a small perturbation of the metric ($|h_{\mu\nu}| \ll 1$ in the coordinate system we are working with). It is convenient to define
$$\bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}h, \tag{18.6}$$
where $h = h_{\mu\nu}\eta^{\mu\nu}$. We introduce $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}$ just because it simplifies the equations.
To first-order in perturbation theory (which we call "linearized gravity"), the Einstein equations reduce to (commas indicate partial derivatives)
$$-\bar{h}_{\mu\nu,\alpha}{}^{\alpha} - \eta_{\mu\nu}\bar{h}_{\alpha\beta,}{}^{\alpha\beta} + \bar{h}_{\mu\alpha,}{}^{\alpha}{}_{\nu} + \bar{h}_{\nu\alpha,}{}^{\alpha}{}_{\mu} = 16 \pi T_{\mu\nu}. \tag{18.7}$$
Most people will agree this is considerably complicated. However, there is a way to make it simpler: the trick Weinberg described. We impose now that our coordinates are such that
$$\bar{h}^{\mu\alpha}{}_{,\alpha} = 0. \tag{18.8a}$$
This can always be achieved with an infinitesimal change in the coordinates. Furthermore, notice Eq. (18.8a) imposes exactly $D$ functional conditions in the metric, just as Weinberg told you. With this condition, Eq. (18.7) becomes
$$-\bar{h}_{\mu\nu,\alpha}{}^{\alpha} = 16 \pi T_{\mu\nu}, \tag{18.8b}$$
which is way simpler.
Eq. (18.8a) may seem arbitrary, but it is just the trick Weinberg mentioned. Furthermore, we do it all the time in electromagnetism. Namely, we very often impose the Lorenz gauge condition
$$A^{\alpha}{}_{,\alpha} = 0,$$
which is remarkably similar to Eq. (18.8a). They are, deep down, the same idea: you impose a condition on the field so that you get rid of spurious (i.e., pure gauge) degrees of freedom, and this greatly simplifies the expressions. This is because you can now focus only on the physical degrees of freedom, and hence you have to describe much less than you usually would.
